# Core Data adding and retrieving to multiple tables how to

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, save

Just a general question to those that know. Ive just learnt my first core data save and retrieve using a single entity (table).
Question is if i wanted to save and retrieve from multiple entities.. what is the best way? Do I need to add more retrieve and save functions? or is there a way of customising the save and retrieve method to do it for multiple entities? for example to add in a sides and also a deserts entity.

here is what I have for the single entity so far:

```
class databasemanager: NSObject {
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    func addRow(name:String, price:String) {
        // set the core data to access the Student Entity
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Pizzas", in: managedObjectContext)
        let pizza = Pizzas(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
        // Assign value to the entity
        pizza.name = name
        pizza.price = price

        do{
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            // showMessage(”OK Adding to Core Data")
        } catch {
            // showMessage(”Error adding to Core Data")
        }
    }

    func retrieveRows() -> String{
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Pizzas", in: managedObjectContext)
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
        request.entity = entityDescription // get the table pizza
        var pizzaObjs = [Pizzas]()

        do{
           try pizzaObjs = managedObjectContext.fetch(request) as! [Pizzas] }
        catch { //show some error msg
        }

        var msg: String = ""

        for pizza in pizzaObjs {
            msg = msg + pizza.name! + ", " + pizza.price! + "\n" }
        return msg
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In coreData, we have wonderful option that is relationship. You can create relationships that may be one to one or one to many. After that create NSManagedObject classes using Edit options that'll create the add or remove methods automatically, so that you can access the multiple entities through main entities.

For more info: [Read this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-25070)